# Failed To Upload File Using Apache FTPclient on Android

Tags: android, ftp-client

I want upload a text file, I am using `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPclient`. The code fails every time.

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    client.connect("192.168.43.164",21);
    client.login("android", "android");
    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    String filename = "/sdcard/m.txt";
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    client.storeFile("/web/m.txt", fis);
    fis.close();
    client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am following this tutorial : [FTP File Upload From Sdcard to server](http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98)

Logcat Output,

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vaibhav.myapplication/com.example.vaibhav.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Application can crashed,

Comment: Show the logcat output.

Comment: Do you sent me ftp upload working codes

Comment: I cant help you without showing the error.

Comment: logcat report

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u6tHiBudJQjRLDI4fbi22QiQXe9xKu-3xyfQKBTKQ60/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sKUVTJmU-N2vJGe_xSQ4TIk3N2KrBeIeg1RluJffhp0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Use an `AsyncTask`. Write the FTP code shown above inside the `doInbackground` method.See the above thread on how to solve the error.

Comment: Bro can you explain me. Cause I'm not a programmer. Plz

Comment: bhai. thanx ...... you advise was great....

FTP WAS successesfully work.

Comment: K Neeraj Lal bhai was great.

Answer (score 0):

FTPClient Upload file.. working for me

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;    
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;     
import android.os.Bundle;     
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;     
import java.io.FileInputStream;     
import java.io.IOException;     
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {     
    @Override     
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
      new uploadTask().execute();     
      }     
    class uploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {    
        @Override    
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {    
            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();     
            FileInputStream fis = null;    
            try {    
                client.connect("192.168.43.164", 21);    
                client.login("android", "android");    
                client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);    
                client.enterLocalPassiveMode();    
                client.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");    
                String filename = "/sdcard/m.txt";    
                fis = new FileInputStream(filename);    
                client.storeFile("/a/m.txt", fis);    
                fis.close();    
                client.logout();    
            } catch (IOException e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();
          }    
                return null;    
            }    
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Great.. Good luck :)